# How to get objects from List of of Avro classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd, avro

I have a Scala List of Avro objects of Avro Class:

```
public class SomeClass extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord { … }


val inputList: List[SomeClass] = // from Json
```

I want to get any of RDD or DataSet to make a mock for the test.

```
val someClasses: RDD[] = ???
```

Could u help me please to find a way?

Comment: Why can you not parallelize this list to create an RDD?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Grand thanks it works. Write please the answer.